# Generate rsa to a specified file

Tags: ssh

I have a rsa in `.ssh` directory

```
me@host:~/.ssh$ ls -al
total 24
drwx------  2 wei wei 4096 3 18 23:50 .
drwxr-xr-x 30 wei wei 4096 3 18 23:37 ..
-rw-------  1 wei wei  748 3 18 10:19 authorized_keys
-rw-rw-r--  1 wei wei    0 3 18 10:17 authorized_keys~
-rw-------  1 wei wei 1675 3 18 10:09 id_rsa
-rw-r--r--  1 wei wei  382 3 18 10:09 id_rsa.pub
-rw-r--r--  1 wei wei  222 3 18 12:09 known_hosts
```

Then to create a new rsa for github account

```
me@host:~/.ssh$ touch github-rsa_key
me@host:~/.ssh$ ls | grep github
github-rsa_key
```

Unfortunately, it report error when tried to generate it

```
me@host:~/.ssh$ ssh-keygen -q -t rsa -b 4096 -f '~/.ssh/github-rsa_key' -C '' -N ''
Saving key "~/.ssh/github-rsa_key" failed: No such file or directory
```

What's the problem with my usage to redirect the output to a new file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you have `~` inside the quotes, thus it will not be interpreted by the shell as your home folder but literally.

Use

```
-f ~/.ssh/github-rsa_key
```

or if you need/want quotes for any reason:

```
-f ~/.ssh/'github-rsa_key'
```

Btw: you don't need to create the file first, `ssh-keygen` will take care of it.